# My kinematic body position and scale are different than the expected position and scale

Tags: c++, c++17, box2d, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a physics system for my "game engine" using Box2D, And when i create a `b2_kinematicBody` The position is bigger than the expected position and the scale is small than the expected scale.

I tried to change the `SetAsBox` parameters with `SetAsBox(this->transform->scale.x, transform->scale.y)` and the same problem

**NOTE**: For the rendering i'm using SDL2 and the positions are based in the SDL2 positions.

[Example of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utUR8.png)

And here is a video of the problem: https://youtu.be/0fMPh8Rk_pY

This is the code of my KinematicBody2D class.

**KinematicBody2D.h**

```
class KinematicBody2D : public Component 
{
    private:
        b2BodyDef k_bodydef;
        b2Body* k_body;
        b2FixtureDef k_fixtureDef;
        b2Fixture *k_fixture;
        b2World* k_world;
        b2PolygonShape polygonShape;

    public:
        KinematicBody2D();
        KinematicBody2D(Scene scene);

        void Start() override;
        void Loop(float delta) override;
        void MovePosition(Vector2 target);
};
```

**KinematicBody2D.cpp** (Just the important part)

```
    void KinematicBody2D::Start()
    {
        this->k_bodydef.type = b2BodyType::b2_kinematicBody;
        this->k_bodydef.position = b2Vec2(this->transform->position.x, this->transform->position.y);
        this->k_bodydef.angle = Math::Deg2Rad(this->transform->rotation);

        this->k_body = this->k_world->CreateBody(&this->k_bodydef);

        this->polygonShape.SetAsBox((this->transform->scale.x / 2.0f), (this->transform->scale.y / 2.0f));

        this->k_fixtureDef.shape = &this->polygonShape;

        this->k_fixture = this->k_body->CreateFixture(&this->k_fixtureDef);
    }

    void KinematicBody2D::Loop(float delta)
    {
        this->transform->position.x = this->k_body->GetPosition().x;
        this->transform->position.y = this->k_body->GetPosition().y;
        this->transform->rotation = Math::Rad2Deg(this->k_body->GetAngle());

        this->polygonShape.SetAsBox((this->transform->scale.x / 2.0f), (this->transform->scale.y / 2.0f));
        this->transform->scale = Vector2(this->transform->scale.x, this->transform->scale.y);

        return;
    }
```

**main.cpp** (Just the important part)

```
int main()
{
    GameObject playerObj = GameObject("Player");
    Scene scene = Scene("Scene", &playerObj);

    playerObj.AddComponent<Sprite>("res/Player.png", Vector4(0, 0, 256, 256), 
    Vector2(64, 64));
    playerObj.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>(scene);
    playerObj.AddComponent<Player>(app.GetRawRenderer());

    GameObject floor = GameObject("Floor", "Floor");
    floor.AddComponent<Sprite>("res/World 1.png");
    floor.AddComponent<KinematicBody2D>(scene);
    floor.transform.position = Vector2(100, 200);
}
```

Comment: One of the parts of programming that keeps the wages high is unless you already know what the problem is, it's usually pretty hard to determine what is important and what isn't.